# Backslash escaping and removal in makefile

Tags: makefile

Given this - rather quaint - makefile, which admittedly was specifically designed to **clearly** illustrate a host of inconsistencies, by trying to find the "rule" how Make handles quoting and backslashes in makefile.

So, the makefile:

```
prereq =   \
\:         \
\\:        \
\\\:       \
\\\\:      \
\\\\\:     \
\\\\\\:

all: % : $(prereq)
    @echo '$+'
%:;
```

Running, I get:

```
: \\: \: \\\\: \\: \\\\\\:
```

Now, let's take a look.

We basically had 6 prerequisites:

1. `\:`
2. `\\:`
3. `\\\:`
4. `\\\\:`
5. `\\\\\:`
6. `\\\\\\:`

Which Make interprets **respectively**, as:

1. `:`
2. `\\:`
3. `\:`
4. `\\\\:`
5. `\\:`
6. `\\\\\\:`

Do you see a pattern here? Well sure there is.

For any **even-number** of backslashes, make take **all** of the backslashes **literally**, and so `\\:` remains `\\:`. `\\\\:` remains `\\\\:`. Finally: `\\\\\\:` remains `\\\\\\:`. No escaping or any interpretation is done at-all.

As for any **odd-number** of backslashes, make **removes** an half of them. To be exact, its an half in the sense of integer-division, where Make removes 1 for 3, 2 for 5. A small twist, for 1 backslash, Make removes 1 backslash. So `\:` becomes `:`, `\\\:` becomes `\:` and `\\\\\:` becomes `\\:`.

Now, sure it must be useful, that make bothers to build all this "theory" for removing backslashes.

But, what is it?

Comment: What version of make?   I get `\: \\: \\\: \\\\: \\\\\: \\\\\\:` as my output (Gnu Make 3.81)

Comment: I get `: \\: \: \\\\: \\: \\\\\\:` with GNU Make 4.0.

Comment: It sounds like a bug in that (and possibly other versions) of make...   What happens if you use `:=` instead of `=`?

Comment: Looks like the colon is the problematic culprit here.  Switching the prerequisites to `a` instead of `:` gets me regular and predictable results.  http://ideone.com/rIqRfM